# Writing a complex function as a power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have been asked to write the following summation as a power series:

$$\sum_{n \geq  500} i^n \frac {z^{5n-2}}{n!}. $$

I know that by comparison to the power series $$\sum_{n \geq  0} a_n (z-a)^n,  $$ we can let $$ a_n = \frac {i^n}{n!},$$ and we can let $$a=0.$$ I am unsure how to represent the $$ n \geq 500 \text { and the power } 5n-2. $$

Thanks

Comment: $i^n z^{5n-2}=\frac{1}{z^2}(iz^5)^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{i^{\frac{n+2}5}}{\left(\frac{n+2}5\right)!}&\text{ if }5\mid n+2\text{ and }n\geqslant2\,498\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by if 5 | n+2 ?

Comment: It means that $n+2$ is a multiple of $5$.

Comment: Oh okay I wasn't even thinking about that function I thought it was a typo! Thanks